# Remote debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have a node.js application hosted in AWS EC2 instance. I ssh into the host with .pem file for authentication. Is there any way I could debug this code in VS Code, I see there is [remote debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_remote-debugging) in VS Code, there is configuration to specify port and host but no option to specify the pem file.

How should I configure VS code to debug?

Answer (score 1):

According to the VS Code documentation on [remote debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_remote-debugging) Node, you need to specify a TCP/IP address and port number for the EC2 instance.  These are set in the `address` attribute of the launch.json file in your workspace's `.vscode` folder.

Here is an example:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to remote",
    "address": "TCP/IP address of process to be debugged",
    "port": "9229"
}
```

Make sure the port (9229 in this example) is included in the rules in your security groups to allow in traffic for this port.  Here is an [overview of rules and security groups for Linux instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) if you need to review this.

Comment: That is for debugging node.js on the ec2-instance. The OP is asking how to edit code that is hosted on the EC2-instance. I'm actually trying to solve that myself.

Comment: I disagree, question title, first paragraph and last sentence ask about debugging, not editing.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue the solution is very simple, bind your inspector to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

so change your package.json script to something like this:

```
scripts:{
 "debug": node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 ./bin/www
 ...
}
```

Reference: https://medium.com/@auchenberg/introducing-remote-debugging-of-node-js-apps-on-azure-app-service-from-vs-code-in-public-preview-9b8d83a6e1f0